# Azure graph api to search groups whose displayName contains a specific term

Tags: azure, search, microsoft-graph-api

I’m using the following Azure graph api to search groups whose displayName contains a specific term (i.e. 123-move), but the response includes names like “123**4**-move” as well. Does anyone know how to do a SQL-Like query (I.e. `select * from groups where displayName like ‘%123-move%’` )?

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$select=id,displayName,description,groupTypes&$orderby=displayName&$top=100&$search=“displayName:123-move”](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$select=id,displayName,description,groupTypes&$orderby=displayName&$top=100&$search=%E2%80%9CdisplayName:123-move%E2%80%9D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created **Azure AD Groups** for testing:

[image]

When I tried to use **Search query**, I got the 1234-move also in the response like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$select=id,displayName,description&$search="displayName:123-move")
```

[image]

So, to search groups whose displayName contains a specific term you have to make use of contains query. But **when I tried to use contains, I got the error like below:**

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$select=id,displayName,description,groupTypes&$filter=contains(displayName,'123-move')
```

[image]

> **Note** that: Contains is not supported in Azure Graph API. Make use of either search or filter parameters only.

So, you can make use of **`startswith`** parameter to fetch the groups which starts `123-move` like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$select=id,displayName&$filter=startswith(displayName,'123-move')
```

[image]

As a **workaround**, you can make use of **PowerShell** to fetch the groups which starts `123-move` like below:

```
Connect-AzureAD

$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like '*123-move*' }
$groups
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for details. So in nutshell, AZURE Graph API does not support contains as of this writing!